# Angular script evaluation takes a lot of time

Tags: angular, optimization

I work on angular project in performance tab in Google Chrome developer tools page take about 3000 ms to evaluate script And in Google test speed web site I have an issue with time to interactive it's also take a lot of time Any suggestions !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can try to use AOT (Ahead of time compilation). It will decrease the scripting time drastically.
2. You can try to use lazy loading by splitting your app into chunks. It will make loading your page faster.
3. You can try to Uglify your app to make it smaller. It will increase the load time.
4. You can update your RxJS to 6 version or newer to reduce bundle size.

Comment: Why would you want to increase scripting time?